# how to reserve the separators of componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: method?

Tags: xcode, nsstring

I have a problem with Xcode: There is a long string containing several sentences. I was required to separate those sentences. So I used the method `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)separator`. The separator is an `NSCharacterSet` with different symbols such as ".?!". This method separates sentences correctly, except that all the punctuations are gone.

For example, the long string is "This is the first sentence. Is this the second sentence?", the result I got is an array containing two sentences "This is the first sentence" and "Is this the second sentence" The period and question mark are missed.

So, how can I reserve the separators of this method?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split strings into linguistic tags like sentences, words, etc. then you are best off using the `NSLinguisticTagger` class introduced with iOS 5.0. From the documentation:

> The NSLinguisticTagger class is used to automatically segment
>   natural-language text and tag it with information, such as parts of
>   speech.

`NSLinguisticTagger` works with many different languages and will make things much easier for you. There is also [WWDC 2012 video 215 - "Text and Linguistic Analysis"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#215) which shows you how to use it.